# NotifyPropertyChanged through code

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

I have a class that contains two other objects.

A variable in the first object bind to `WPF` element, call it `X`.

A similar variable in the other object.

I want that when the PropertyChanged event happens, it will change the variable in the second object.

Here is the code that does not work for me:

The class that contains the variables: (I had register to property changed event)

```
private Class1 _var1;
    public Class1 Var1
    {
        get { return _var1; }
        set
        {
            _var1= value;
            if (_var1!= null)
                _var1.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(_var1_PropertyChanged);
            else
                _var1.PropertyChanged -= new PropertyChangedEventHandler(_var1_PropertyChanged);
        }
    }

    void _var1_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      if(e.PropertyName=="X")
        Var2.X= Var1.X;
    }

    private Class2 _var2;
    public Class2 Var2
    {
        get { return _var2; }
        set { _var2= value; }
    }
```

Class 1:

```
    private int _x;
    public int X
    {
        get { return _x; }
        set
        {
            if (_x!= value)
            {
                _x= value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("X");
            }
        }
    }
```

class 2:

```
public int X { get; set; }
```

`PropertyChanged` work in class 1 but he did not come to an event I created in a class that contains the two variables, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you mean, but if I had a class with 2 variables that I wanted to change together, I would try the following:
First, define some `SetAndNotify` method or you'll get a headache from the `PropertyChanged` events:

```
public void SetAndNotify<T>(ref T field, T value, Expression<Func<T>> exp)
{
    if (!Equals(field, value))
    {
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(exp);
    }
}
```

Add it to some base class that will handle this event.

Second, in your setter for `Var1` you register for the change event and not set anything, is that on purpose?

Third and last, there's no problem with changing more than one property in a setter, but make sure it's the public property that you change:

```
private SomeType privateVar1;
public SomeType PublicVar1
{
    get { return privateVar1; }
    set
    {
        SetAndNotify(ref privateVar1, value, () => PublicVar1);
        MyOtherPublicVar = someNewValue; // this will activate the property's setter.       
    }
}
```

I hope this helps. If not, please try to clarify your question.